# Triggering based on commit author

Tags: github, github-actions

Let's consider a GitHub Actions workflow like this (based on [this one](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/.github/workflows/ci.yml)):

```yaml
name: CI
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  lint:
    ...

  unit-test:
    ...
```

Currently, this workflow is triggered on every commit, no matter which user authored the commit.

Would it be possible to configure the workflow so it gets triggered only when the author *is not* a given one (i.e. `user1`)? How?

Comment: At the `on` level you can see what triggers are supported [in the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on), and: no. But you can put a condition on a job (or step) with [`if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe's feedback I have fixed the workflow this way:

```yaml
name: CI
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  lint:
    if: github.actor != 'user1'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ...

  unit-test:
    if: github.actor != 'user1'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    ...
```

It is not optimal (as the `if` clause has to be repeated in every job) but suffices for my case.